# MongoDB projection on C++

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-cxx-driver

I need to write a code to get some data from my MongoDB and generate a json file, but i can't understand how to do a projection.
The mongoShell command which i have to "translate" in C++ is:

```
db.projects.find({},{'school_state': 1, 'resource_type': 1, 'poverty_level': 1, 'date_posted': 1, 'total_donations': 1, '_id': 0});
```

Thanks to everyone who can help me !

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to something similar as in this [mongocxx's github repo example](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/eccd8b0a525f72d85d6153085e299c291d02acec/examples/mongocxx/query_projection.cpp#L44) or [this other one](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/8b8271c75af06e060c742112d2b46459c3a7b7d0/examples/mongocxx/mongodb.com/documentation_examples.cpp#L806):

```
mongocxx::options::find opts{};
opts.projection(make_document(kvp("school_state", 1), kvp("resource_type", 1), kvp("poverty_level", 1), kvp("date_posted", 1), kvp("total_donations", 1), kvp("_id", 0)));

auto cursor = coll.find({}, opts);
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! in the documentation i did't found a simple example like this